# How much more scroll do I have in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say the scroll bar is at a certain place, is there a way for me to know, in pixels how much more scroll I have?

I'm using jQuery scrollLeft: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/
but I don't want to overrun the value...

Answer (score 0):

Use element.scrollHeight, element.scrollWidth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollWidth

Compatability: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

However, don't worry about overrunning the value -- the browsers will adjust to the max anyway.

Comment: i think you will have to subtract the current screen width/height from these numbers to know how much scroll is left. I think that is what you are after but this will only apply when the user is viewing the uppermost left hand corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html

great set of cross-browser solutions here...